# How to use UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How to use `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`?

Should I declare it in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` to reload data when coming from background to foreground.

Does `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` gets called only when app comes from background to foreground?

Please help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sometimes it is useful to have a listener of *UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification* when you need to make some action in your view controller on wake up from background (in case you entered to background with this view controller on-screen). In such wake up *viewWillAppear* will not be triggered!

Example of use:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someMethod)     name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

}

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    <YOUR CODE AT WAKE UP FROM BACKGROUND>
}
```

Of course, you can also implement all you need at your app delegate class life cycle.

Answer (score 4):

You get this notification if your app was interrupted by a phone call or push notification. Generally, if your application is getting active on screen after interruption.

You can register any class, that is loaded in memory by the moment application will become active as observer to this notification.

Use following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(someMethod:)
                                         name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Use `someMethod` to handle this notification. And don't forget to remove this class as observer in `dealloc`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                            name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                          object:nil];
```

Comment: In general case it is better or add observers of general type (not necessarily in this case) in viewWillAppear and remove at viewWillDisappear because in many cases you don't need to monitor events while your controller is not on screen. Sometimes it event leads to errors.

Comment: Mentioned errors (= implicit problems) arise in many projects I monitored. It is not the system problems - it is architecture problems. Usually developers (especially junior devs) understand working cycle on-screen. But they change something in viewWill(Did)Disappear and forget that after that viewController can be still alive (in tab bar for example) and continues to receive notifications which are treated now behind the scene.

Answer (score 3):

The OP asked about system notifications fired when the app is backgrounded and then foregrounded again. The Notification designed to handle this situation is the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification and UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification. If you want a notification that fires for a wider range of situations, such as when you have a system notification, take a phone call, a SMS comes in, or you slide up the control pane, as well as being backgrounded then you will want the UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification and UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification. It's important to recognize that these are different, since you might only need to react if your app is backgrounded, and not for other scenarios.